# Pass a NULL value to numeric parameter via Yii in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, yii

I have written a function in PostgreSQL with a single parameter of type `NUMERIC`. I am attempting to call that function from a webapp developed using the Yii framework via the SqlDataProvider component. However, each time the parameter value is left empty, I keep getting the following error:

```
Ivalid input syntax for type 'numeric'.
```

Whenever I try to execute the function directly via PhpPgAdmin, everything seems to work flawlessly.

Below is the code for the discussed PL/pgSQL function `search(..)`:

```
search("itemcode" character varying DEFAULT NULL, "taxpercentage" numeric DEFAULT NULL)
LANGUAGE plpgsql
    AS $$
BEGIN  
   SELECT * FROM item WHERE (itemcode IS NULL OR item.item_code LIKE itemcode||'%')
      AND (taxpercentage IS NULL OR item.tax_percentage = taxpercentage);
END;
$$;
```

In the Yii model, I have also created a search function which in turn calls the database-level PL/pgSQL function:

```
public function search()
    {       
        $count=Yii::app()->db->createCommand("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM  search('$this->item_code','$this->tax_percentage')")->queryScalar();
        $sql="SELECT * FROM search('$this->item_code','$this->tax_percentage')";
        $dataProvider=new CSqlDataProvider($sql, array(
        'totalItemCount'=>$count,
        'pagination'=>array(
        'pageSize'=>10,
        ),
        ));
        return $dataProvider;
    }
```

How can I pass a NULL value to parameter of type `NUMERIC`?

All help will be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: That is not valid code for a function in Postgres. Please show the complete function definition

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name The function is very long one, there is no issue with the function as it runs correctly in phppgadmin. Problem is when passing value from yii framework. Also issue is with null value only. If I pass other values it is working.

Comment: @user1690835: if it runs in psql, give its signature and highlight how yii is calling it if you can locate that. it's probably an issue with yii's ORM whereby the latter is filling the param with e.g. an empty string or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by checking for empty in the search function and using parameterized query. So the modified function is

```
public function search()
    {    
if(empty($this->tax_percentage))
        $this->tax_percentage=null;

    $count=Yii::app()->db->createCommand("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM  search(:item_code,:tax_percentage)")->queryScalar();
    $sql="SELECT * FROM search('$this->item_code','$this->tax_percentage')";
    $dataProvider=new CSqlDataProvider($sql, array(
    'params' => array(':item_code' => $this->item_code,':tax_percentage' => $this->tax_percentage),
    'totalItemCount'=>$count,
    'pagination'=>array(
    'pageSize'=>10,
    ),
    ));
    return $dataProvider;
}
```